# jquery not displaying image from JSON array created with php

Tags: php, jquery, html, json

I want to create an array of image file names in php, then display the images one at a time in the browser.

## The code:

getpics.php:

```
<?php
$photo_array = [];
   $handle = opendir(dirname(realpath(__FILE__)).'/spades50/');
        while($file = readdir($handle)){
            if($file !== '.' && $file !== '..'){
                array_push($photo_array, "$file");
            }
        }

echo json_encode($photo_array);
?>
```

## html / query:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <script src="getpics.php"></script>
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js">           </script>
<script>

$.ajax({
        url: "getpics.php",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
            $.each(data, function(i,filename) {
                $('#imageDiv').prepend('<img src="spades50/'+ filename +'"><br>');
                //console.log(filename); // shows the file names in the console log
            });
        }
    });

    </script>

    </head>
<body>

<h2>This is a heading</h2>


<img class="#imageDiv" src="loading2.gif" />

</body>
</html>
```

## Result:

The page only shows the initial image loading2.gif, if I uncomment this line: //console.log(filename); I can see the files being loaded in the console window but they are not displayed.

I am new to jquery so any tips will be greatly appreciated.

Regards,
John ......

Comment: class use dot notation to access, # is for id, change your class="#imageDiv" to id="imageDiv" and see if it works

Comment: Check if the image src url id rendering correctly by using firebug

Comment: where is your imageDiv id?

Comment: `$('.imageDiv').prepend('<img src="spades50/'+ filename +'"><br>');` and then `<img class="imageDiv" src="loading2.gif" />`   OR  `$('#imageDiv').prepend('<img src="spades50/'+ filename +'"><br>');`  and `<img id="imageDiv" src="loading2.gif" />`

Comment: lol why you are appending it to an image instead of div

Comment: [quote] lol why you are appending it to an image instead of div [/quote] - thanks for the insightful, helpful comments Newbie Dev, lol .......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several problems in your code: try this (untested):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>

      $.ajax({
        url: "getpics.php",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
          $.each(data, function(i,filename) {
            $('#imageDiv').prepend('<img src="spades50/' + filename + '"/><br>');
          });
          $('#loader').hide();
        }
      });

    </script>

  </head>
  <body>

    <h2>This is a heading</h2>

    <div id="imageDiv">
      <img id="loader" src="loading2.gif" />
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

**First:** you don't have to insert **`getpics.php`** as script in your header.

**Second:** class="#imageDiv" is wrong. A class is prepended by a **dot ( . )** and an **ID** is prepended by a **#**. So if you want to use an ID use **`id="imageDiv"`**

**Third:** prepend is to add html nodes as first element into a container. You told jQuery to prepend the new images to an image tag which is not a container element. ([documentation](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/)) So to prepend you have to use a div e.g.
Or you use **insertBefore();** ([documentation](http://api.jquery.com/insertbefore/))

I assume that you want to hide the loader when all images are loaded. I made this by adding the line **`$('#loader').hide();`**.

Comment: Adrian, thank you for the constructive comments, I have amended the code as per your suggestions and am about to read the documentation you linked to, it is working in the sense that the images are loading, not how I want them yet but it is a great start, thanks again.

Comment: I tested this on a local machine and it works perfectly. What is the output of your PHP script? Can you post it?

Comment: The php file makes an array of file names pointing to photos ( there are about 1200 photos), if I run getpics.php the output is in the format (jason_encoded) : ["39_ortho111_289.jpg","42_ortho111_207.jpg","68_E-IMG_0227.jpg","96_B-IMG_0031.jpg","106_E-IMG_0130.jpg","145_A-IMG_0077.jpg","153_C-IMG_0701.jpg","206_B-IMG_0093.jpg","252_B-IMG_0004.jpg" ........... "wiz_1001.jpg","wiz_1002.jpg","wiz_1003.jpg"]

Comment: You have certainly answered my original questions and the photos are being displayed, I am now just trying to get a handle on the jQuery/ajax structure, so I can maybe manipulate the array data in the $.each() loop ..... more reading for me, thanks again.